# Is it possible to compute the density plot from a k-means clustering in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have performed a cluster analysis on my data and have obtained the results. I would like to plot the results from k-means=3 in a density plot and compute the intersection between the three groups to generate two thresholds to be able to divide my data.

My code for the k-means is the following:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
AP <- read_excel("file.xlsx")
ggplot(AP, aes(x = volume)) + geom_density() + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(volume, na.rm = T)),
             colour = "red", linetype ="longdash", size = .8)

library(cluster)
fit3       <- kmeans(AP, 3)
y_cluster3 <- fit3$cluster

fit1       <- kmeans(AP, 1)
y_cluster1 <- fit1$cluster

fit4       <- kmeans(AP, 4)
y_cluster4 <- fit4$cluster

fit2       <- kmeans(AP, 2)
y_cluster2 <- fit2$cluster

clusplot(AP, fit3$cluster, stand=TRUE,color=TRUE, labels=0, lines=0)
clusplot(AP, fit1$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=6, lines=0)
clusplot(AP, fit4$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
clusplot(AP, fit3$cluster, stand=TRUE,color=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
```

[image: This is the result from the clustering]

This is what I would like to obtain and compute the intersections:
[image]

The dataset is made of values of diferent volumes (v^3) and ratio (ares/volume). I based my analysis on the ratios and I would like to obtain the threshold values based on the ratios. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recalculate the densities for each cluster, and find the points where density of one becomes higher than the other, i.e switches

I use the iris dataset as an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
#exclude species
df = iris[,-5]
df$clus = factor(kmeans(df,3)$cluster)
p1 = ggplot(df,aes(x=Sepal.Length,col=clus)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Now we write the density function for each cluster subset. Key is to have the same coordinates, using from and to option from density()

```
#define x limits
LIMS = range(df$Sepal.Length)
#function to extract y values (i.e density)
dens_grid = function(x,start,end){dens = density(x,from=start,to=end)$y}

# we iterate through each cluster, and get density for each cluster
# from start to end
DM = do.call(cbind,by(df$Sepal.Length,df$clus,dens_grid,start=LIMS[1],end=LIMS[2]))
# xcoordinates
xcoord = density(df$Sepal.Length,from=LIMS[1],to=LIMS[2])$x
```

we can look at this density matrix, and it starts from left (x at 4.3) where the density of cluster 3 is higher than others..

```
head(cbind(xcoord,DM))
       xcoord            1            2         3
[1,] 4.300000 0.0002591290 3.547236e-17 0.2362330
[2,] 4.307045 0.0002982119 4.715919e-17 0.2463309
[3,] 4.314090 0.0003417903 4.890658e-18 0.2563679
[4,] 4.321135 0.0003901271 4.153097e-17 0.2663234
[5,] 4.328180 0.0004453972 8.467460e-17 0.2761633
[6,] 4.335225 0.0005087817 1.222466e-16 0.2858354
```

For every row, we can get the cluster with highest density:

```
apply(DM,1,which.max)
  [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 [38] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 [75] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[112] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[149] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[186] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[223] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[260] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[297] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[334] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[371] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[408] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[445] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[482] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

You can see it switches from 3 to 1 around 165th entry, and from 1 to 2 at a later point. To get these "switches", we do

```
switches=which(diff(apply(DM,1,which.max))!=0)+1
xcoord[switches]
[1] 5.455382 6.279648

p1 + geom_vline(xintercept=xcoord[switches])
```

[image]